# Blender 2.8 - How do you copy things like rigidbody constraints to other objects?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I found an answer 4 years ago, which is no longer valid for blender 2.8, can anyone help me?

update: all suggested solutions are used to copy RigidBody or Constrain, but not "Rigid Body Constraint". I need to apply rigid body constraints, after the generation of fragments with CellFracture

Unfortunately I don't find or exist "copy rigidbody contraint"

[image]

UPDATE: 
I found a temporary solution, after applying the cell fracture, I create a single object, with (Ctrl+J) and I assign the rigidbody constraint, and then I separate with (P) -> by lose part.

Comment: it must be missing in 2.8, maybe warn the developers

Comment: Unfortunately I think so, I hope someone can help me with scripts.